# Convert just the content of a figure to an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am currently using `getframe()` and `frame2im` in MATLAB to convert a figure of a plot to an image.

I just realized that this is working almost like a screenshot of the figure, with all the axes and labels taken into account as well.

How can I convert JUST the contents of the figure (aka the "plot") into an image?
I don't really want to save all of them to file first.

Comment: Look into this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883859/convert-a-plot-with-ellipses-to-binary-image-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getframe / cdata` idiom.  What this will do is that if you call `getframe` on the **current frame** in focus without any parameters, it will return a structure to you that contains a structure element called `cdata`.  This stores the **RGB** pixel array of **just the figure contents** themselves.  The axes and labels are not captured - only what is painted onto the figure is captured.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(im);
h = getframe;
out = h.cdata;
figure;
imshow(out); %// Should give you the contents within the imshow frame.
```

FWIW, I also answered this same question here, though it was for a different situation:    [keep new image when drawing lines by dragging the mouse in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898746/keep-new-image-when-drawing-lines-by-dragging-the-mouse-in-matlab/23900647#23900647)

Comment: Following Divakar's link, I used `set(gca, 'visible', 'off')` which worked as well. Now I don't know which one is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, cdata DOES NOT WORK. I had a major problem recently with the same thing - the only work around i could find is to crop each image after using getframe and cdata - this will work fine for images that are all the same size (ugly as it is - you just need to find the grey edges in the image), but if the images are all different, this wont work (well, it wont work well. there might be some way to automatically adjust the crop size)

Comment: `cdata` will work if there **is only one plot**, which I am assuming that's what the OP is intending to capture.  Obviously, if there are multiple subplots then this won't work.  Also, FWIW, this should really be placed in a comment.  This does not answer the question the OP is asking.

Comment: cdata grabs borders, and is exactly what OP didn't want